# folium can't use pop up text

Tags: python, folium

I use this code to test pop up text.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
folium.Circle(
    location = [45.372, -122.6972],
    radius = 100,
    popup='inline explicit Popup',
    color='red',
    fill=False
).add_to(m)
m.save(r'E:/test.html')
```

But when I open the html and click the red circle, no text pops up.
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to fix it.And Only in some special positions of the red circle, it will display.

```
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
popup=folium.Popup('inline explicit Popup',show=True)
folium.Circle(
    location = [45.372, -122.6972],
    radius = 100,
    popup=popup,
    color='red',
    fill=False
).add_to(m)
m.save(r'E:/test.html')
```

[image]